# What is needed to get this DateFormatter working?

Tags: swift, nsdateformatter

I am having trouble getting the date formatter to output a date when given a string. The code I am using is below:

```
        let formatter = DateFormatter()

    formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_GB")
    formatter.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'")

    if let date = formatter.date(from: string){
        return date
    }else{
        print("Fail: " + string)
        print("Form: yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'")
        return Date(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(0))
    }
```

The date I am using is "2017-03-22T17:09:16Z". However, the result always comes back as nil (runs the fail loop). I have tried both versions from the DateFormatter documentation (this and the "Working With Fixed Format Date Representations" section).

This string should be valid, but it is not working. The string originates from an array of bytes in ascii format, converted using the appropriate init function from String.

The question is, what am I missing?

Comment: Agree with Rob's answer also check this: http://nsdateformatter.com  to see different dateFormat and their examples.

Comment: Unrelated to your issue but do you really want `Date(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(0))`? That will return the date of January 1, 1970 at midnight UTC time.

Comment: The date that it outputs is just a placeholder so that I can spot an error. Curiously, when i copy and paste the string, and use it as a hard coded value, my code works. It's only the string that I've processed from the byte stream that has issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of issues:

1. Do not use `setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate`. That's for showing localized date strings in the UI. But you need a literal date string. Use `dateFormat` instead.
2. Do not use `en_GB` locale. Use `en_US_POSIX`. See Apple [Technical Q&A 1480](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1480/_index.html).
3. If you are going to look for a literal `Z` (surrounded by quotes), you have to set the `timeZone` of the formatter to GMT/UTC/Zulu, too. Or, better, just use `Z` without quotes, `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ`, which will correctly interpret the `Z` in the input string as a designator of the GMT time string. The code, as written in the question, will not adjust for time zones properly.

Thus:

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()

formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"

if let date = formatter.date(from: string) {
    return date
} else {
    ...
}
```

---

By the way, [`ISO8601DateFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/iso8601dateformatter), introduced in iOS 10 and macOS 10.12, gets you out of the weeds about worrying about locales, time zones, and format strings. It parses the ISO 8601/RFC 3339 date format for you:

```
let formatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()

if let date = formatter.date(from: string) {
    return date
} else {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I need this code to run on iOS 7 and above (customer requirement). I can use #available to use both methods however.

Comment: Strangely, when I copy and paste my date string from the output and input it as a literal, the date conversion works. The string as used is converted from an array of UInt8 encoded in ASCII, before it is fed into this function. It then undergoes various things that remove trailing/leading whitespace etc.

I am wondering if a hidden character is slipping through. I'd expect more indication of this though.

Comment: If we could see what that array of values looked like, we should be able to diagnose it.

Comment: There was a control character hidden in the string. There was a mistake where the string was created that caused it to get through.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong function of DateFormatter.
It should be a setter of `dateFormat`

```
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"
```

You *should* remove the `'` between the Z as well. Because `"2017-03-22T17:09:16Z"` will work with the hardcoded `'Z'` but won't work with `"2017-03-22T17:09:16+02:00"`.

However if you set:

```
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
```

It can understand any timezone